# how to use "data defined override" in qgis 2.0?

Tags: qgis, labeling

How can I use the new "data defined override"-funktion in qgis 2.0? I did not find any further information about it in the handbook an somewere else. 
I want to label my layer with different front styles for example:

if the field "type" = 'city' and 'town' -> the label have to be in size 12pt and bold

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create all kinds of expressions for the font size. Based on your example, I guess you would use some [**CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END** statements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator).

[image]