# Many ELSE statement in Expression in QGIS (2.6)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

is it possible to have more than one ELSE in the `CASE WHEN` statement in the Expression builder in QGIS?

For example:

```
CASE WHEN "population" > 5000
THEN 'big'
ELIF WHEN "population" > 1500
THEN 'medium'
ELSE 'small'
END
```

I know that this piece of code is totally wrong, but I'm not able to find an equivalent of `ELIF`..

Some ideas? Am I looking at the problem in the wrong way?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I'm sorry..

The equivalent of `ELIF` is `WHEN`.

This question has been already answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator).

Sorry for the noise.