# How can I copy non-blank values to a new column from different columns in the same layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

My data:

```
n1    n2    n3    NEW_COLUMN
11    null  null
null  33    null
null  null  55
```

My desired result:

```
n1    n2    n3    NEW_COLUMN
11    null  null  11
null  33    null  33
null  null  55    55
```

Comment: Have a read of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator and use the IsNull operator.

Comment: Will there always be only a single non-null value for any given row? If not, how do you pick which one?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the **Coalesce** function which returns the **first non-NULL** value from the given columns (fields). Insert this expression into the *Field Calculator* as a new field:

```
coalesce( "Field_1", "Field_2", "Field_3" )
```

---

Below is a simple example:

[image: Simple example]

[image: Field calculator]

[image: Result]

---

If a feature has columns with multiple values (eg. `1, NULL, 3`), then you may need to include *ElseIf* statements to decide which values to take.

Hope this helps!