# Editing Attribute Table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

How can I type an expression that give me specific text based on another field value? I added an image of example data.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Icarus! You can use an expression like `CASE WHEN "KAR_KOD" = 9 THEN 'ibreli' WHEN "KAR_KOD" = 100 THEN 'karisik' END`. This post might also help: [Elseif Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator)

Comment: Thank you guys for all help, I will try that expression and let you know result.