# Prioritising polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, command-line

I just created a layer in which I hand drew a lot of polygons.

Now I want to fill out the Attribute table through commands since it will save me a bunch of time.

Therefore, I calculated the area of each polygon using `$area/10000` to have the size in `ha`.

I want to prioritize each area

- above 10 ha as Prio 1
- each below 1 ha as Prio 3
- each in between as Prio 2

Does anyone have a smart solution to the problem?

My closest approach is: `IF ("Size ha" > 10, 1, 2)`

That however still leaves me with having to distinguish the areas of Prio 2 to Prio 3 manually.

Comment: Just a general annotation: The expamples given on the different tools in the field calculator are quite useful to picture, how the tools work.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```py
if($area/10000 > 10,1,if($area/10000 < 1,3,2))
```

Just a capsuled if-condition, first checking for areas greater 10 ha, then checking for those smaller than 1 ha, then giving everything else Prio 2.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `CASE`-statement

```sql
CASE
  WHEN "Size ha" >= 10 THEN 'Prio 1'
  WHEN "Size ha" > 1 AND "Size ha" < 10 THEN 'Prio 2'
  WHEN "Size ha" <= 1 THEN 'Prio 3'
END
```

Or as was provided by [@Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik), the upper formula can be rewritten using the `if`-statement

```py
if("Size ha" >= 10, 'Prio 1', if("Size ha" <= 1, 'Prio 3', 'Prio 2'))
```

---

**References:**

- [Expressions | Conditionals](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#conditionals)
- [Elseif Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39168/elseif-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I tried using **WHEN** clauses, but somehow didnt end up at a fitting result. My command looked different though. I will try it out!

Comment: Another possbile solution, though I do not like doublechecks on conditions, they tend to be a bit complicated in my experience.

Comment: @Erik, can you be so kind and refer me to one of such issues when applying doublechecks on conditions? Thank you

Comment: @Taras that is my own judgement, I usually mess up conditions when having to check upper and lower boundaries ;-)

Comment: @Erik, I think I will happen to me as well. However, when I have for instance 20 conditions I will be lost within a number of parenthesis in If-condition :-)

Comment: Is there a solution, where I could have another collum which only holds the prio information? Similar to *If collum "Area_size" > 10, THEN "Prio" = 1*?

Comment: Just create a new column and fill it with CASE formula.

Comment: True, that was my mistake all along. I tried to fill in the column with a condition regarding its own. Thanks. You both have been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `AND` in the `CASE-WHEN-...` construct. Since the first matching result is returned, you can simply make an ascending order of the values you would like to test for:

```
CASE
  WHEN "Size ha" <= 1 THEN 'Prio 3'
  WHEN "Size ha" < 10 THEN 'Prio 2'
  ELSE 'Prio 1'
END
```

Note also, that there is no explicit test needed for `"Size ha" >= 10`.

Comment: Yes, you right!